# Let p>1. Show that $L^p[0,1] \not\subset L^1[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let p>1. Show that $L^p[0,1] \not\subset L^1[0,1]$

This is what we created, is this enough to proof the question? Or do we need more information.

Let
$f(x)=a_n$, if $x \in (\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}]$ for n=0,1,2,... and for some a.

We will obtain,

$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx= \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{a_n}{2^n}$ and

$\int_{0}^{1} f^p(x) dx= \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{a^p_n}{2^n}$

Now all you want to do is to take some sequence such that the $a_n$ converges and $a_{n}^p$ diverges

Comment: This looks good to me. Best to take positive $a_n$.

Comment: For every $p>1$ and $t\geqslant0$, $$t\leqslant1+t^p$$ Integrating this yields $$\|f\|_1\leqslant1+\|f\|_p^p$$ Thus, $$L^p([0,1])\subset L^1([0,1])$$ (And the exercise is wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\int_0^1|f|\leq \sqrt[p]{\int_0^1|f|^p}$ by Holder...$L^p(0,1)\subset L^1(0,1)$.

Comment: @WillM. To me, show that $L^p(0,1)\not\subset L^1(0,1)$ mean : show that there is $f\in L^p(0,1)$ s.t. $f\notin L^1(0,1)$.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @WillM. Then $f$ is necessarily in $L^1$ since $\int_0^1|f|\leq \|f\|_{L^p}$

Comment: @WillM. : Here [Holder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality). They say : if $f\in L^p$ ang $g\in L^q$, then $fg\in L^1$. So here $f$ doesn't need to be in $L^1$ to use Holder. Only $L^p$.

Comment: Holder holds for all nonnegative measurable $f,g$ even if they are not integrable.

Comment: @WillM. What? Sorry but what are you talking about? If $f$ is not integrable (on $[0,1]$ for the Lebesgue measure) and $p>1$ then $|f|^p$ is not integrable either (on $[0,1]$ for the Lebesgue measure) .

Comment: You are right.

In general: $\mathscr{L}^p \subset \mathscr{L}^1$ for finite measure spaces and, in contrast, $\mathscr{L}^1 \subset \mathscr{L}^p$ for totally atomic measure spaces.

Comment: @Did: could you tell me why my answer is wrong ? I just apply Holder, no ? (and I can, no ?)

Comment: But your answer is **not** wrong, young padawan... And please do not start me on the topic of how mse users vote... :-)

Comment: You are right: see for example [this paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function#Lp_is_a_subspace_of_L1,loc_for_all_p_≥_1) in the Wikipedia entry on Locally integrable functions

Comment: @WillM.: I really don't follow you...$L^p$ is the set of Lebesgue measurable function... what is your atomic measure space ?

Comment: @Did : thank you :)

Comment: I was wrong, and you were right. The set $\mathscr{L}^p$ will be a subset of $\mathscr{L}^1$ whenever $p \geq 1$ and the measure space has finite measure.

Comment: @WillM. **Not true** either, sorry.

Comment: @Did, corrected. Thanks.